# Storing non UUID string in UUID field in postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql-9.4

I have some strings like 12344 ( 4-5 digit numbers) which I want to store in postgresql table with column data type as UUID. These are the columns that need to be indexed. From the document it seems UUID is field having some format like a0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a11 with 128 bit quantity.

So is it possible to store string like 12344 in UUID data field? Currently getting " invalid type input string error"

```
  pstmt.setObject(1,"12344",java.sql.Types.OTHER);
```

Comment: No, not possible. A column with the data type `uuid` does not accept invalid UUIDs.

Comment: Ok thanks for confirming

Answer (score 1):

Not directly. But you can build an UUID from a long value:

```
    long val = 12344;
    pstmt.setObject(1,new UUID(0, val),java.sql.Types.OTHER);
```

Note that the value will be "UUID-encoded", so you won't be able to do some `select * from table where val = 12344`. You will have to compute the corresponding UUID first.